# Explicit on N-ary constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, explicit-constructor

In this presentation: http://qtconference.kdab.com/sites/default/files/slides/mutz-dd-speed-up-your-qt-5-programs-using-c++11.pdf

The author suggests that N-ary constructors benefit from the C++11 version of `explicit` keyword.

What changed in C++11 that makes this keyword useful if you have more than one constructor parameter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++11, if you have a non-explicit constructor for a class `A` that has multiple parameters (here I use `A::A(std::string, int, std::string)` as an example), you can initialize an argument of that type with brace initialization:

```
void foo(A a);
foo({"the", 3, "parameters"});
```

Similarly, you can do the same with return values:

```
A bar() {
  return {"the", 3, "parameters"};
}
```

If the constructor is, however, `explicit`, these will not compile. Hence, the `explicit` keyword now has importance for all constructors, rather than just conversion constructors.

Comment: Could you give an example where it is useful to forbid brace initialization? What harm could brace initialization do?

Comment: @Ali Someone on the new standard C++ committee public forums pointed to this question that should more or less answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157041/what-could-go-wrong-if-copy-list-initialization-allowed-explicit-constructors