# Uniform initialization in return statement and explicit conversion operator to bool

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I tried to force explicit conversion in return statement by means of using of uniform initialization syntax as it is in following:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{

    explicit
    operator bool () const
    {
        return false;
    }

};

bool
f()
{
    return {A{}}; // error: no viable conversion from 'void' to 'bool'
    // equivalent to return bool{A{}}; at my mind
}

bool
g()
{
    return static_cast< bool >(A{});
}

struct B
{

    B(A) { ; }

};

B
h()
{
    return {A{}};
    // equivalent to return B{A{}};
}

inline
std::ostream &
operator << (std::ostream & _out, B const &)
{
    return _out << "B";
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << f() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << g() << std::endl;
    std::cout << h() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But got an error, as it pointed against correspoinding line of code into comment.

Why deduced type of `{A{}}` is `void`? What is the meaning of `return {/* something */};` in general? How it differs from obvious uniform initialization during simple initialization?

The compiler used is *clang 3.6.0*.

Comment: If you try `explicit B(A) { ; }`, it might help understand it.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157041/what-could-go-wrong-if-copy-list-initialization-allowed-explicit-constructors

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes WRT `explicit B(A) { ; }`: error is *error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization*. It sounds strange, considering `B b{A{}};` not raising any error.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes OK, quote `In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.` is somehow relevant to the question. But `bool` at my mind have no explicit constructors at all.

Comment: @Orient but your conversion function is `explicit`

Comment: @PiotrS. Anyways it is *conversion-to*, but not *conversion-from* in some sense.

Comment: @Orient *"A conversion function may be explicit (7.1.2), in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion **for direct-initialization** (8.5).*"

Comment: @PiotrS. Two above quotes gives the part of an answer.

Comment: @Orient as for the `void`-related issue, *braced init list* has no type at all, hence `void`

Comment: @PiotrS. I'm under impression. Really it has no type?

Comment: @PiotrS. Even so, what is the trigger to consider it as initializer of `B` in another case?

Comment: @Orient special rules called *copy-list-initialization* / *direct-list-initialization*, or *list-initialization* in general

Comment: @PiotrS. `void` doesn't mean "no type at all". `void` is a type; it means "no *value* at all". So, I don't think the fact that a *braced init list* is not an expression and has no type can be seen as a valid reason for `void` appearing in that error message.

Comment: @PiotrS. OK, what about `bool f() { return {bool{}}; }`?

Comment: GCC 5.1.0 gives a better error message: `cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'bool' in return`, which makes sense. MSVC14 RC gives an even better diagnostic: `'return': cannot convert from 'braced-init-list' to 'bool'` `note: Reason: cannot convert from 'A' to 'bool'` `note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called`, which makes even more sense and precisely reflects what the standard specifies for this initialization.

Comment: @Orient: `bool f() { return {bool{}}; }` is a direct-list-initialization with a braced-init-list containing a [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) temporary bool variable.

Comment: @davidhigh It's not *direct-list-initialization*, it's *copy-list-initialization*. The initialization that occurs in function return is *copy-initialization*.

Comment: @bogdan: in principle, yes. But in the context of copy-elision it seems to be direct-initilization: *When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be moved or copied into an object of the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualification), the copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where it would otherwise be moved or copied to.* from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: @davidhigh your quote is irrelevant, even if copy-elision takes place the rules stay the same, copy-initialization remains copy-initialization

Comment: @PiotrS, Bogdan. ok, thanks for correction. Should have better read point (8) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make the user-defined conversion `explicit`, you are forced to explicitly state what you want.

Remove the explicit and it works fine:

```
struct A
{
    operator bool () const
    {
        return false;
    }

    operator bool ()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

bool
f()
{
    return A{};   // conversion from A to bool
    return {A{}}; // conversion from braced-init list to bool 
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I'll try to work out your reasonable questions:

With `bool{A{}};` you apply *[direct-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)* and then return the result (which in the general case implies a move, a copy or RVO). But as there is no implicit conversion from `A{}` to `bool`, it fails. Why? Because an explicit conversion operator only participates in *direct-initialization* or explicit casts, see point (2) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

The second case where you return `{A{}}` is similar, but you first construct the init-list and then pass it to copy-list-initialize the bool return value. So the same problem as in `bool{A{}};` occurrs.

EDIT: for the reason why there is a `void` involved, see the comments by @PiotrS.

Comment: "*conversion from std::initializer_list<A> to bool*", braced-init-list is not the same as `initializer_list`

Comment: @PiotrS.: thanks, just figured that out by myself and already corrected it

Comment: Why `return {A{}};` and `return bool{A{}};` differs?

Comment: What is the source of `void`?

Comment: I extended the answer but it seems @PiotrS. already did all that -- better -- in the comments :-)