# Why does the compiler report the return type of this method as void?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a custom wrapper for `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>

template<typename Key, typename Value> 
struct keyed_vector {

  typedef Value value_type;
  typedef Key size_type;
  std::vector<Value> values;

  keyed_vector( std::initializer_list<Value> init ) : values(init) {}

  size_type size() const { return static_cast<size_type>(values.size()); }
};
```

I wanted to make sure that the compiler error when trying to use the return
value of `size()` as a `size_t` was sane, so I wrote a quick test:

```
#include <cassert>
int main() {
  struct my_size_type {
    size_t t;
    explicit my_size_type(size_t t) : t(t) {}
  };

  keyed_vector<my_size_type, int> vec{};
  {
    size_t actual_size {vec.size().t}; // this should compile cleanly
    assert(actual_size == 0u);
  }
  {
    size_t actual_size {vec.size()}; // this should be a compiler error
    assert(actual_size == 0u);
  }
}
```

And while the compiler did fail, the error message I got was different than I expected:

```
$ g++ --stdlib=libc++ -std=c++1y -Wall -Wextra -Werror keyed_vector_example.cpp
keyed_vector_example.cpp:28:10: error: no viable conversion from 'void' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
  size_t actual_size {vec.size()}; // this should be a compiler error
         ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I would have expected "`error: no viable conversion from 'my_size_type' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')`".

Why is the compiler (`Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)`) reporting the
return type of `vec.size()` as `void` here?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I [found the reason in the comments to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479383/uniform-initialization-in-return-statement-and-explicit-conversion-operator-to-b#comment49038727_30479383). It's because I'm using an initializer list.

If I switch the code to:

```
size_t actual_size = vec.size(); // this should be a compiler error
```

Then I get the much clearer error:

```
$  g++ --stdlib=libc++ -std=c++1y -Wall -Wextra -Werror keyed_vector_example.cpp
keyed_vector.cpp:28:10: error: no viable conversion from 'size_type' (aka 'my_size_type') to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
  size_t actual_size = vec.size(); // this should be a compiler error
         ^             ~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It looks like other compilers give a better error message for braced initializer lists, so if this really bothers me I should file an issue with clang.