# Why not checking the explicitness of a constructor when matching it?

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

The following behavior is rather strange to me:

```cpp
class Y
{
public:
    Y(int) { cout << "Y\n"; }
};
class X
{
public:
    X(int, const Y&) { cout << "int, const Y&\n"; }
    explicit X(int) { cout << "X\n"; }
    X(int, X&&) { cout << "int, X&&\n"; }

    X(const X&) { cout << "copy\n"; }
    X(int, int, const Y&) { cout << "int, int, const Y&\n"; }
    explicit X(int, int, int) { cout << "3 ints\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    X x1(1, 2);         // OK
    X x2({ 1,2,3 });    // error, OK if X(int, int, int) becomes, say, X(int, int, X&&)
}
```

In my understanding, `X x1(1, 2);` is OK because when the compiler tries to make an `X&&` from `2`, it finds that `X(int)` is `explicit`, hence the compiler treats `X(int, const Y&)` as a better match (had `X(int)` not been `explicit`, `X(int, X&&)` would be the better match). On the other hand, `X x2({ 1,2,3 });` is not OK because while `X(int, int, int)` is treated as the better match (since there is not restriction for initializing the 3 `int`s by `1`,`2` and `3` respectively), it is `explicit` and thus cannot be called implicitly.

Why don't the compiler just check the `explicit`ness on `X(int, int, int)` and "take a step back" to prefer `X(int, int, const Y&)` as the better match?

---

The answers mentioned that ambiguity will arise if `X(int)` is not `explicit`. In fact, I [find](https://godbolt.org/z/Pz4h93jne) that for msvc C++20/17/14 there will not be ambiguity error, while gcc and clang will report the error... why...?

Comment: `X x2({ 1,2,3 });` is interpreted as `X x2(X{ 1,2,3 });`: create a temporary using three-ints constructor, then copy-initialize from that temporary (the copy is ultimately elided). This doesn't work because three-ints constructor is explicit. The syntax to call three-ints constructor directly would be `X x2(1,2,3);` or `X x2{1,2,3};` With the choice of syntax you use, the compiler has to look for (1) a one-parameter constructor that (2) can take an object constructible from brace-init list `{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OP's question is why if it is copy-initialization the `explicit` constructor is not simply ignored and the other non-`explicit` one chosen, which is how it works with usual copy-initialization. Also `X x2(X{ 1,2,3 });` is direct-list-initialization followed by direct-initialization (the latter skipped over since C++17), no copy-initialization.

Comment: @CPPL For your edit: MSVC has a [bug](https://godbolt.org/z/dfEr3b7vc).

Comment: @AnoopRana So... can I say `X&&` is preferred over `const X&` only when object of type `X` is passed directly? (situations like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/n4K1d5rMj))

Comment: @CPPL No, in your given demo the `X&&` version is choosen because `X(2)` is a prvalue. If you were to pass an lvalue, then the `const X&` version will be preffered/choosen. See [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/1yyA3ageV)

Comment: @AnoopRana Sorry I actually mean "an rvalue expression representing object of type `X` is passed directly"

Comment: @CPPL Yes, as long as it(object of type `X`) is an rvalue `X&&` will be preferred.

Comment: @AnoopRana Thanks :) but btw, this can be another "strange" implementation for me: why wouldn't just make an rvalue passed, which can be implicitly converted into an `X`, to be preferred by `X&&`? haha...

Comment: @CPPL The question in your last comment wasn't clear. In particular, i mean i didn't understand what you're asking when you said: *"why wouldn't just make an rvalue passed, which can be implicitly converted into an `X`, to be preferred by `X&&`?"* . Maybe you can give a demo to clear that up or ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @AnoopRana I mean if we pass an rvalue of type `X`, then `X&&` is preferred over `const X&` (as the `X(2)` in your demo). Here in the above code, the `2` in `X x1(1,2)` will first need to be used to construct an `X` temporary or an `Y` temporary in order to call `X(int, const Y&)` or `X(int, X&&)`. The current implementation will report ambiguity at this stage. But since `2` in `X x1(1,2)` is an rvalue, I think the compiler could just be implemented to select `X(int, X&&)` rather than giving ambiguity. That would be more consistent with the case where we pass `X(2)`. Just some random thoughts

Comment: @CPPL Soppose `X::X(int)` is not explicit. Then the reason it can't happen this time is because now there are two conversion sequences using `X::X(int, X&&)` and `X::X(int, const Y&)` that are **equally ranked**. And so the compiler won't try anything further as it know one can't be chosen over other. But by making `X::X(int)` explicit you've made one of the conversion sequence better than the other.  That is they are no more equally ranked. As the one that will use `X::X(int, X&&)` isn't even viable anymore because it will use an explict `X::X(int)` ctor.

Answer (score 2):

> (had X(int) not been explicit, X(int, X&&) would be the better match)

No, in that case the overload resolution would have been ambiguous, because there is no ordering between different user-defined conversions. Even if one will in the end up binding a rvalue reference and the other a lvalue reference, neither will be considered better than the other.

> Why don't the compiler just check the explicitness on X(int, int, int) and "take a step back" to prefer X(int, int, const Y&) as the better match?

The only possible constructor to use for the initialization

```
X x2({ 1,2,3 });
```

is the copy constructor of `X`. All other constructors expect either multiple arguments (but there is only one here) or expect a single `int`, which cannot be initialized from a three-element brace-enclosed initializer list.

So, the question is how to get from `{1,2,3}` to `const X&` in the copy constructor's parameter. Since you don't have any `std::initializer_list` constructors (which would be preferred), this will simply be tested by doing overload resolution again against the constructors of `X` with three arguments.

The rules for this are a bit different than normally for copy-initialization. Instead of ignoring `explicit` constructors, in the case of initializer list arguments they *are* considered, but if overload resolution ends up choosing one, then the initialization is considered ill-formed. This special behavior for initializer list arguments is specified in [[over.match.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.list#1.sentence-2).

That's why the compiler doesn't "back-track" or ignore the `explicit` constructor, although it can't be used.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157041/what-could-go-wrong-if-copy-list-initialization-allowed-explicit-constructors) for discussion on the motivation behind this rule for initializer list arguments. There is also [CWG issue 1228](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1228) arguing that this is counter-intuitive. It was closed as "not a defect", but unfortunately only with a remark that the behavior is intended.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see on case by case basis what is happening and why in the first case(`X x1(1, 2);`) the program works but in 2nd case (`X x2({ 1,2,3 });`) we get ambiguity error.

##### Case 1

Here we consider:

```
X x1(1, 2);
```

The explanation given for this case in your question isn't correct. In particular, you said that if we remove the `explicit` from the `X::X(int)` ctor then `X::X(int, X&&)` would be the better match, **which is not true**. You can confirm this [here](https://onlinegdb.com/pHrEVBdK8). As you will see in the above linked demo, if we removed the `explicit` from `X::X(int)` ctor then we will get an **ambiguity error** between the `X::X(int, X&&)` and `X::X(int, const Y&)` ctors. Note msvc has a bug as it [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/dfEr3b7vc) the program when `X::X(int)` is not explicit.

This means that both `X::X(int, X&&)` and `X::X(int, const Y&)` have the **same rank** and so the compiler cannot decide which one to choose.

Thus, when you made `X::X(int)` an `explicit` ctor you decided for the compiler that the `X(int, const Y&)` ctor should be used because now the other ctor `X::X(int, X&&)` would use an user defined `explicit` ctor . Thus only the `X(int, const Y&)` remains viable.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider:

```
X x2({ 1,2,3 });
```

The reason this case fails is because here the `X::X(int, int, int)` is a **better match** than the `X::X(int, int, const Y&)` ctor. That is, here the compiler has already decided that the `X::X(int, int, int)` should be used. But because this ctor is `explicit` we get the error saying:

```
converting to ‘const X’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘X::X(int, int, int)’
```

##### Summary

Case 1 doesn't fail because there the compier hasn't decided which of the two `X::X(int, X&&)` and `X::X(int, const Y&)` equally ranked ctors to choose. It can't because they are equally ranked. But by making `X::X(int)` `explicit` you have made the decision that the `X::X(int, const Y&)` should be choosen over `X::X(int, X&&)`.

While Case 2 fails because there the compiler has decided that the `X::X(int, int, int)` is a better match than the `X::X(int, int, const Y&)`. But since `X::X(int, int, int)` is `explcit` this fails with the mentioned error.

---

> I find that for msvc C++20/17/14 there will not be ambiguity error, while gcc and clang will report the error... why...?

It seems to be [bug](https://godbolt.org/z/dfEr3b7vc) in msvc.